# How to Count the Number of Column Labels Named With Numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to count the number of columns with number-named label.

```
  movie_id  1   2   5   6   7   10  12  13  borda   rank
0   1       5   4   4   4   0   4   0   3   24      1
1   2       3   0   3   0   0   0   0   3   9       3
2   3       4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4       4
3   4       3   0   0   0   5   4   5   5   22      2
4   5       3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   4       4
```

In this case, ideally the columns to be counted are columns `'1'`, `'2'`, `'5'`, `'6'`, `'7'`, `'10'`, `'12'`, `'13'`. In other words, those columns with non-number named label won't be counted.

I need to deal with DataFrames with thousands of columns, so it's impossible to count the columns by man. My thought is that this might have something to do with `loc` or `iloc`, but I have no idea how to accomplish it with codes.

Comment: What is expected output? Columns `borda` and `rank` or `8` ?

Comment: My expected output is 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need count number of columns with numeric use [`str.isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) with `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
out = df.columns.astype(str).str.isnumeric().sum()
print (out)
8
```

Comment: @Nihal - hmmm, give me some time.

Comment: This too will not work if COLUMN name is same. e.g. 1 and 1.

Comment: @GauravKP - Why do you think so? It depends if OP need number of unique values of not

Comment: I mean you run your code with same column name. e.g 
 movie_id  1   1  1   6   7   10  12  13  borda   rank

Comment: @GauravKP - So what is expected outpuf from it? All `1` are count like one value?

Comment: There won't be columns with identical labels, so it's not an issue for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to count the amount of columns named with numbers, you can use the following list comprehension:

```
sum(str(x).isnumeric() for x in df.columns)
# 8
```

Comment: It will *not* work if column name is same. Else it will work.

Comment: It works fine for me. There's no column names that are the same. Thanks!